# DynamoDB backup and restore using Data pipelines. How long does it take to backup and recover?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, database-backups, amazon-data-pipeline, disaster-recovery

I'm planning to use Data pipelines as a backup and recovery tool for our DynamoDB. We will be using amazon's prebuilt pipelines to backup to s3, and use the prebuilt recovery pipeline to recover to a new table in case of a disaster.

This will also serve a dual purpose of data archival for legal and compliance reasons. We have explored snapshots, but this can get quite expensive compared to s3. Does anyone have an estimate on how long it takes to backup a 1TB database? And How long it takes to recover a 1TB database?

I've read amazon docs and it says it can take up to 20 minutes to restore from a snapshot but no mention of how long for a data pipeline. Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Does the newly released feature of [exporting from DynamoDB to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.html) do what you want for your use case? To use this feature, you must have continuous backups enabled though. Perhaps that will give you the short term backup you need?

Comment: This feature is a "one-way-street". I tried exporting to S3, but you can't reimport back to S3. this is only for analysis purposes and not for backup. this is most useful for AWS Athena and Redshift!

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know why you're not planning to use the built-in backup mechanism. It offers point in time recovery and it is highly predictable in terms of cost and performance.

The Data Pipelines backup is unpredictable, will very likely cost more and operationally it is much less reliable. Plus getting a consistent snapshot (ie point in time) requires stopping the world. Speaking from experience, I don't recommend using Data Pipelines for backing up DynamoDB tables!

Regarding how long it takes to take a backup, that depends on a number of factors but mostly on the size of the table and the provisioned capacity you're willing to throw at it, as well as the size of the EMR cluster you're willing to work with. So, it could take anywhere from a minute to several hours.

Restoring time also depends on pretty much the same variables: provisioned capacity and total size. And it can also take anywhere from a minute to many hours.

[Point in time](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pitr/) backups offer consistent, predictable and most importantly reliable performance regardless of the size of the table: use that!

And if you're just interested in dumping the data from the table (i.e not necessarily the restore part) use the new export to S3.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are a few reasons why I'm using BOTH.
1. Point-in-time-Recovery (PITR) is NOT safe from Ransomware. It uses the same encryption as the base database
2. Turning off PITR will delete the backup making it susceptible to accidental deletion or malicious deletion of the whole table
3. It doesn't protect against account take over, where having an S3 backup means I can spin up another instance in a different account really quickly

So, I'm using S3 backup for archival and BCDR and PITR for consistent/quick recovery! We are using both to account for all threats.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case you can definitely go with a Data Pipeline or similar strategy but you’ll have to test yourself to figure out how long it takes in your particular case. The biggest problem is definitely the fact that you have to stop writing to the table before you execute the data copy operation

Comment: are you sure there will be "down-time" during the "export to s3" action? I've watched this video that claims there is no downtime. The export might not be consistent, but I don't think it will inhibit writing to the table? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xvXoz-amtk

Comment: This is the official docs on capacity: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-prereq2.html so I don't think I will have to stop writing, just manage it such as running during less busy times!

Comment: There won’t be down time. You can still access the data for reads but if you continue to write then the backup may be inconsistent. Whether that is a problem depends on your use case. You mat also want to look into streaming the table activity using DynamoDB streams.. that way all writes can be manually replicated to another ‘backup’ table in another account. A much better solution IMO, if you are concerned about account being compromised.

Comment: This is a fair point. this doesn't help with Archival needs as well as the cost basis. S3 is significantly cheaper albeit the backup might be a *little inconsistent*.  Thank you so much for all your input and advice! :D

Comment: @VineethSai Would you mind sharing what approach did you end up taking

Comment: @SKhurana Went with AWS backup for cross-account-cross-region but for using Data pipelines for DynamoDB instead of Global tables

Comment: @VineethSai Thanks for your response. I suppose data pipeline for dynamodb instead of AWS backup because Cross-account backup does not currently support Amazon DynamoDB tables, Correct? What was your reason for going with data pipeline for dynamo instead of ddb streams with lambda as claimed by AWS to be cheaper and faster here  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/cross-account-replication-with-amazon-dynamodb/